# Parsing XML is stop because in XML have special symbol ( ' )

Tags: xml, swift

i have xml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bitrix/js/main/core/core.js?1302607145"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">BX.message({'LANGUAGE_ID':'ru','FORMAT_DATE':'DD.MM.YYYY','FORMAT_DATETIME':'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS','COOKIE_PREFIX':'BITRIX_SM'})</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bitrix/js/main/core/core_ajax.js?1302607147"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bitrix/js/main/session.js?1302607142"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bxSession.Expand(86400, 'fe05ffe85fe71cfbda890bd6e53822c9', false, 'a0a1120039d68a6bdfc189342fcbcb3a');
</script>
```

I parse this XML

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    html = elementName }
```

and parsing stop because found ' symbol. How replase this?

Comment: Either wrap the textual content with `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`, or replace all apostrophes with `&apos;`.

Comment: "I have XML" ... No, it looks like you have HTML, which is not the same thing. Consider using HTML parser, such as [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). See http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios.

Comment: how to replace an apostrophe if it web-xlm and I need to read first?

Comment: @Rob This XML file with HTML elements. I am not all it copy-paste.

Comment: There's no such thing. It could be XML that has HTML as one of its values (in which case the HTML should be wrapped with `CDATA` or `&`, and `<` (and, optionally, `>`) should be replaced with `&amp;` and `&lt;` (and `&gt;`). But you shouldn't attempt to have XML parser parse the HTML. Run your "XML" through `xmllint` command line app and it will show you all the issues. Bottom line, if this is from a XML feed, then it doesn't appear to be well-formed. Can you fix the source?

Comment: Thank you! Probably the source will be easier to fix.